# How to continue the loop while web scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a simple script in order to explore how to web scraping with python. I picked this URL: https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Mens-Coats-Jackets/57988/bn_692010

There are 48 item in the page and every single item has a brand, style etc. detail except 16th item and my code is stopping when it comes to 16th one. So my question is how can I continue this loop or how can I say pass these details. Here is my code in below;

```
    from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


my_url = 'https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Mens-Coats-Jackets/57988/bn_692010'

#opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

#grabs each product
containers = page_soup.findAll('div',{'class':'s-item__wrapper clearfix'})

filename = 'ebayproducts1.csv'
f = open(filename, 'w+')

headers = 'product_name, item_price, item_style, shipping_detail\n'

f.write(headers)

contain = containers[0]
container = containers[0]

for container in containers:
    product_name = container.h3.text

    item_details_container = container.findAll('div',{'class':'s-item__details clearfix'})
    item_price = item_details_container[0].div.text

    item_style = item_details_container[0].findAll('span',{'class':'s-item__detail s-item__detail--secondary'})[0].text

    shipping_detail = item_details_container[0].findAll('span',{'class':'s-item__shipping s-item__logisticsCost'})[0].text


    print('product_name: '+ product_name)

    print('item_price: ' + item_price)

    print('item_style: ' + item_style)

    print('shipping_detail: ' + shipping_detail)

    f.write("%s,%s,%s,%s\n" %( product_name, item_price, item_style, shipping_detail))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely encountering some element or tag in your `containers` list that is different than all the other elements you are searching for.

You could change how you specify your `containers` list by changing your search parameters in the `soup.findAll()` method.

Try printing `containers` and finding why the 16th item in that list is different, and adjust your search accordingly.

Alternatively, you could use a try except, something like this:

```
for container in containers:
    try:
       product_name = container.h3.text
       item_details_container = container.findAll('div',{'class':'s-item__details clearfix'})
       item_price = item_details_container[0].div.text
       item_style = item_details_container[0].findAll('span',{'class':'s-item__detail s- 
       item__detail--secondary'})[0].text
       shipping_detail = item_details_container[0].findAll('span',{'class':'s-item__shipping s-item__logisticsCost'})[0].text

       # etc ...

    except <name of your error here, eg. TypeError>:
        print(f'except triggered for {container}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that some items are not present and you cannot test for this on position or selector alone in all cases e.g. Style. You can test for style being present in text of container. Someone with more Python knowledge could probably tidy this up into something more pythonic and efficient

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import pandas as pd
pattern = re.compile(r'Style:')
url = 'https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Mens-Coats-Jackets/57988/bn_692010?_pgn=1'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
results = []
for item in soup.select('.s-item'):
    x = item.select_one('.s-item__title')
    title = x.text if x else None
    x = item.select_one('.s-item__price')
    price = x.text if x else None
    x = item.select_one('.s-item__shipping')
    shipping = x.text if x else None
    x = item.find('span', text=pattern)
    style = x.text.replace('Style: ','') if x else None
    results.append([title, price, shipping, style])

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(df)
```